# Interrupt running program and save data

Tags: c++, c, linux

How to design a C/C++ program so that it can save some data after receiving interrupt signal.

I have a long running program that I might need to kill (say, by pressing Ctrl-C) before it finished running. When killed (as opposed to running to conclusion) the program should be able to save some variables to disk. I have several big Linux books, but not very sure where to start. A cookbook recipe would be very helpful.

Thank you.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to do that, you need to make your program watch something, for example a global variable, that will tell him to stop what it is doing.

For example, supposing your long-running program execute a loop, you can do that :

```c
g_shouldAbort = 0;
while(!finished)
{
   // (do some computing)

   if (g_shouldAbort)
   {
      // save variables and stuff
      break; // exit the loop
   }
}
```

with g_shouldAbort defined as a global ***volatile*** variable, like that :

```
static volatile int g_shouldAbort = 0;
```

(It is very important to declare it "volatile", or else the compiler, seeing that no one write it in the loop, may consider that if (g_shouldAbort) will always be false and optimize it away.)

then, using for example the **signal** API that other users suggested, you can do that :

```
void signal_handler(int sig_code)
{
   if (sig_code == SIGUSR1) // user-defined signal 1
      g_shouldAbort = 1;
}
```

(you need to register this handler of course, cf. [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal).

```
signal(SIGUSR, signal_handler);
```

Then, when you "send" the SIGUSR1 signal to your program (with the **kill** command for example), g_shouldAbort will be set to 1 and your program will stop its computing.

Hope this help !

NOTE : this technique is easy but crude. Using signals and global variables makes it difficult to use multiple threads of course, as other users have outlined.

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do isn't trivial. You can start by installing a signal handler for SIGINT (C-c) using `signal` or `sigaction` but then the **hard part** starts.

The main problem is that in a signal handler you can only call [async-signal-safe functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html) (or [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29) functions). Most library function can't be reliably considered reentrant. For instance, `stdio` functions, `malloc`, `free` and many others aren't reentrant.

So how do you handle this ? Set a `flag` in you handler (set some global variable `done` to `1`) and look out for `EINTR` errors. It should be safe to do the cleanup **outside the handler**.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do falls under the rubric of checkpoint/restart.

There's several big problems with using a signal-driven scheme for checkpoint/restart. One is that signal handlers have to be very compact and very primitive. You cannot write the checkpoint inside your signal handler. Another problem is that your program can be *anywhere* in its execution state when the signal is sent. That random location almost certainly is not a safe point from which a checkpoint can be dropped. Yet another problem is that you need to outfit your program with some application-side checkpoint/restart capability.

Rather than rolling your own checkpoint/restart capability, I suggest you look into using a free one that already exists. gdb on linux provides a checkpoint/restart capability. Another is DMTCP, see http://dmtcp.sourceforge.net/index.html .

Answer (score 0):

Use `signal(2)` or `sigaction(2)` to assign a function pointer to the `SIGINT` signal, and do your cleanups there.

Answer (score 0):

Make your you enter only once in your save function

```
// somewhere in main
signal( SIGTERM, signalHandler );
signal( SIGINT,  signalHandler );

void saveMyData()
{
    // save some data here
}

void signalHandler( int signalNumber )
{
    static pthread_once_t semaphore = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
    std::cout << "signal " << signalNumber << " received." << std::endl;
    pthread_once( & semaphore, saveMyData );
}
```

If your process get 2 or more signals before you finish writing your file you'll save weird data

Comment: for c++ your can consider boost::call_once